# How to exit the entire call stack of shell scripts if a child script fails?

Tags: bash, shell, exit

I have set of shell scripts, around 20-30, that are used for performing one big task as a whole. The wrapper script calls mainly the high-level task scripts but internally those scripts calls other scripts  like and the flow goes on in a nested manner.

I want to know if there is a way to exit the entire call stack if some critical script fails. Normally I run `exit 125` command and then catch that in caller script and so on but I feel that little complicated. Is there a special exit that will abort the entire call stack? I don't want to use `kill` command to abort the wrapper script process.

Comment: I think you have it right, there is no way to quit out of call stack composed of subprocesses. the best I can offer is to wrap your call like `echo "at step 2 fpr example"; if /path/to/script2 ; then if /path/to/script3 ; then echo "as deep as we go" ; else exit 125 ; else exit 124 ; fi`. Good luck.

Comment: Agree with @shellter. It's hard to quit a call stack if they are processes. My suggestion is to use bash functions in a single shell process. You can still maintain several script files, but you need to `source` them instead of executing them.

Comment: @WuYongzheng : yes, good idea! Good luck to all.

Comment: Thanks all.. I will wait to see if someone posts a better solution than what I am using

Answer (score 0):

You could have your main wrapper script start every sub-script in its own process group, using e.g. `chpst -P`.

Then the sub-scripts, as well as their children, could kill their own process group by sending it a KILL signal, and this would not affect the main wrapper script.

I think this would be a bad idea and what you're currently doing is the good way, though (because it makes the code easier to follow).

Comment: Thanks but I don't want to kill the processes abruptly. It should end the script call stack gracefully including the wrapper script. As such I am doing that exit 125 logic but its very difficult from maintenance perspective. I need to be very careful to catch every exit point.

Comment: Then functions are probably the way to go, as suggested previously.